# Can java streams be chained without using only the constructors?

Tags: java, stream, constructor-chaining

I know there is a way streams can be chained by using the constructors as following :

```
BufferedReader bf=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(io.openStream()));
```

But, is there another way doing so?

```
SetSink/SetProcess();
```

Perhaps?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using constructors?

Comment: I don't , just wondering if it is possible.

One reason could be that I have built a really long chain,
and just want to change the sink stream as the end
instead of building a new one.

Answer (score 0):

As you can't use a wrapped Stream without something to wrap, the answer is

a) no you can't and

b) you wouldn't want to.

> One reason could be that I have built a really long chain, and just want to change the sink stream as the end instead of building a new one.

In this case you can use intermediate variables like

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(filename);
if (filename.endsWith(".gz"))
    in = new GZIPInputStream(in);
in = new BufferedInputStream(in);
if (objectStream)
   return new ObjectInputStream(in);
return DataInputStream(in);
```

Comment: As I commented above,

if I built a long chain for file X, and I want the same for file Y

once I finished with X, there is no way of using the already built chain?

too bad :(
thanks

Comment: There is no requirement for the chain to be all on one line or in only one combination. see above.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the javadoc for the [BufferedReader class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html), the only way to build it is to pass a reader in the constructor.

Any reason not to use the constructors?

Comment: Yeah, I have looked in the javadoc and I noticed thats the only
way. But I wondered if there is a higher path of doing so.
(Like using the Reader super class or such)